# How to use django filter_fields with ArrayField in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using a Postgres ArrayField in my models. I am trying to use django filters but I get an error for them.

AutoFilterSet resolved field 'flavor' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type ArrayField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'. See: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides

Model

```py
class Items(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    matches = ArrayField(models.CharField(
        max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
    category = ArrayField(models.CharField(
        max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
    flavor = ArrayField(models.CharField(
        max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
    special = ArrayField(models.CharField(
        max_length=200), blank=True, default=list)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

ViewSet

```py
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Items.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filter_fields = ('item', 'category')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I figured it out, lol. Needed to create a custom filter with lookup_exp='icontains'.

```py
class CategoryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ('item', 'category')
```

```py
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Items.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filterset_class = CategoryFilter
```

Comment: What is 'CategorySerializer' here?

Comment: Upvoted the answer but it won't work without filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement some specific lookups for ArrayField, try this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.array import SimpleArrayField
from django_filters.filters import Filter

class ArrayOverlapFilter(Filter):
    field_class = SimpleArrayField

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs.setdefault("lookup_expr", "overlap")
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When you define in FilterSet you have to specify base_field:

```
devices = ArrayOverlapFilter(base_field=CharField())
```